# print numerical values from array in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a process which is getting launched by two different processes(one is by **init** and other by **lxc** container)

I am trying to get the pids of the process using process name by command `$(pidof $PROCESS_NAME)`,
which works fine. The command gives 2 pid values , but when i try to print the individual values
using `a=(${process_pids[0]})` and `b=(${process_pids[1]})` only first command yields the first value, second one prints empty.

Also the length is showing as 1 despite we have two elements in the array `process_pids`

On the other way if we enable `numbers_normal=(1234 5678)` instead of `process_pids=$(pidof $PROCESS_NAME)` , though `echo "pids = $numbers_normal"` print only one value, the indexing is working fine.

What is the problem with the statement `process_pids=$(pidof $PROCESS_NAME)` and how to correct it.

```
#!/bin/sh
PROCESS_NAME=process1
process_pids=$(pidof $PROCESS_NAME)
#numbers_normal=(1234 5678)
echo "pids = $process_pids"
a=( ${process_pids[0]} )
b=( ${process_pids[1]} )
echo "0th = $a"
echo "1st = $b"
# lengths are showing as 1, but the number of items are 2
echo "length = ${#process_pids[*]}"
echo "L = ${#process_pids[@]}"

for i in ${process_pids[@]}; do
    echo "pid $i parent is $(ps -o ppid= -p $i)"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use arrays, use a shell with array support such as `zsh`, `bash`, `ksh` or `yash`. The `sh` language has no arrays (though some `sh` implementations do implement *some* array support as an extension in a variety of ways). So here, the she-bang should be `#! /bin/bash -`, not `#!/bin/sh`.

Then, you need to initialise `process_pids` as an array:

```
process_pids=($(pidof -- "$PROCESS_NAME"))
```

Note the extra parentheses around the process substitution. Your current assignment sets `process_pids` as a scalar.

By leaving the `$(...)` unquoted within the `array=(...)` declaration, we're invoking the split+glob operator (split only with `zsh`), and assuming `$IFS` has not been modified, the output of `pidof` will be split on the newline or space characters that `pidof` uses to separate pids in its output.

With this, your loop will work correctly, with quotes (as intended with `[@]`):

```
for i in "${process_pids[@]}"; do
```

Comment: There's also that anti-pattern of thinking one has to store intermediate results in variables.  In this particular question, there is no need for any arrays. You can read from `pidof` (or `pgrep`) directly with an unquoted command substitution in a `for` loop (assuming `$IFS` is sane), or safer, in a `while` loop using `read`.

Comment: @they, or even, on Linux distributions (which the `pidof` command suggests the OP is using): `ppids=( $(ps -o ppid= -C "$PROCESS_NAME" | sort -nu) )`